# Translating mouse coordinates to world space coordinates

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

I'm using GLFW and I want to get world space coordinates by mouse coordinates on window to drawing objects while clicking in selected place. Firstly I was trying to get this coordinates using only matrices transformations but as a result i did not get anything with sense.

```
glfwGetCursorPos(window, &xPos, &yPos);
mat4 inverse_projection = glm::inverse(projection);
mat4 inverse_view = glm::inverse(view);

GLdouble normalized_coord2D_x = (2.0 * xPos / -1.0),
    normalized_coord2D_y = (2.0 * yPos / -1.0);

vec4 worldCoordNear;
vec4 worldCoordFar;

vec4 normalizedCoordNear = vec4(normalized_coord2D_x, normalized_coord2D_y, -1.0, 1.0);
vec4 clipCoordNear = normalizedCoordNear;
vec4 eyeCoordNear = inverse_projection * clipCoordNear;
worldCoordNear /= worldCoordNear.w;

vec4 normalizedCoordFar = vec4(normalized_coord2D_x, normalized_coord2D_y, 1.0, 1.0);
vec4 clipCoordFar = normalizedCoordFar;
vec4 eyeCoordFar = inverse_projection * clipCoordFar;
worldCoordFar = inverse_view * eyeCoordFar;
worldCoordFar /= worldCoordFar.w;
```

Now I gave up from that solution and trying to solve the problem with gluUnProject on simple 2D scene, my function looks like:

```
void mouseButtonCallback(GLFWwindow *window, int button, int action, int mods)
{
    if (button == GLFW_MOUSE_BUTTON_LEFT && action == GLFW_PRESS) {
    std::cout << "Left button pressed" << std::endl;

    GLdouble xPos, yPos;
    glfwGetCursorPos(window, &xPos, &yPos);

    GLint viewport[4];
    GLdouble modelview[16];
    GLdouble projection[16];
    GLfloat winX, winY, winZ;
    GLdouble posX, posY, posZ;

    glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modelview);
    glGetDoublev(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projection);
    glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, viewport);

    winX = (float)xPos;
    winY = (float)viewport[3] - (float)yPos;
    glReadPixels(xPos, int(winY), 1, 1, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, &winZ);

    gluUnProject(winX, winY, winZ, modelview, projection, viewport, &posX, &posY, &posZ);
    }
}
```

And I am getting error:

> LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _gluUnProject@48 referenced in
>   function "void __cdecl mouseButtonCallback(struct
>   GLFWwindow*,int,int,int)"
>   (?mouseButtonCallback@@YAXPAUGLFWwindow@@HHH@Z)

I am working on VS2015 and that's my includes:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <GL/GLU.h>
#include <Windows.h>
```

It is worth pointing out that the glu library I downloaded with NuGet Packages

I would be very grateful for all the help and an explanation on how to solve the problem.

Comment: Just pointing out the obvious. But since it's a linker problem, are you sure you're linking and providing the correct path to the lib file?

Comment: where can i find glu32.lib then? cause i cant find it and i saw that gluUnProject need Glu32.lib, I only linked opengl32.lib, glew32.lib, glfw3.lib

Comment: Ok, i solved the problem, but the question now is if I use perspective, will gluUnProject return good values?

Answer (score 0):

Basically your projection matrix will take vertices from camera/eye space to clip space then it does perspective divide to get normalised device coordinates.Then what ever viewport you have mentions using that window transform will be applied on it to get screen coordinates. gluUnProject is doing this in reverse order for you. So rest assured it will give to good values.

Answer (score 0):

It's important to know exactly what you're trying to do and the variables at play. So to convert the mouse coordinates into coords that can interact with a model's vertices goes like this.

In screen space the coordinates start at the top left corner, (0, 0) and end at the bottom right corner (screen width, screen height)

World space operates using a grid system that's between -1 and 1 on both the x and y axis. So what you're trying to do is convert the width/height based coordinates into a -1/1 based coordinates.

To do this think of the coordinate system and your current position as a distance on a string. The current location of your mouse coordinates is simply your mouse having traveled X% of this string's total distance.

The conversion method that I've found works best uses the following variables; the total size of the world space grid, which is the value 2. The percentage of distance traveled on a particular axis, which is the x or y coordinate divided by the width or height respectively. The final variable is an offset of 1, which is required because the top left corner of the screen in world space is (-1, 1), and not (0,0).

The equation for converting your current x axis will look something like this:

```
float worldX = 2*(mouseX/screenWidth)-1;
```

The equation for the y axis is almost identical. Where the symbols of the 2 and 1 constant values are inverted due to how the viewport transformation works. The Y axis equation looks like this:

```
float worldY = -2*(mouseY/screenHeight)+1;
```

It's important to note that the system's actual screen resolution can prevent the above equations from producing accurate results. To ensure proper precision set the window's width and height relative to your display's actual aspect ratio. If you don't do this you will have to manually resize the window and the frame buffer size callback will correct the issue.